# The right way to use a data structure in OCaml

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, ocaml

Ok, I have written a `binary search tree` in OCaml.

```
type 'a bstree = 
    |Node of 'a * 'a bstree * 'a bstree
    |Leaf


let rec insert x = function
    |Leaf -> Node (x, Leaf, Leaf)
    |Node (y, left, right) as node -> 
        if x < y then
            Node (y, insert x left, right)
        else if x > y then
            Node (y, left, insert x right)
        else
            node
```

---

I guess the above code does not have problems.

When using it, I write

`let root = insert 4 Leaf`

`let root = insert 5 root`

...

**Is this the correct way to `use/insert` to the tree?**

I mean, I guess I shouldn't declare the root and every time I again change the variable root's value, right?

If so, how can I always keep a root and can insert a value into the tree at any time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like good functional code for inserting into a tree. It doesn't mutate the tree during insertion, but instead it creates a new tree containing the value. The basic idea of immutable data is that you don't "keep" things. You calculate values and pass them along to new functions. For example, here's a function that creates a tree from a list:

```
let tree_of_list l = List.fold_right insert l Leaf
```

It works by passing the current tree along to each new call to `insert`.

It's worth learning to think this way, as many of the benefits of FP derive from the use of immutable data. However, OCaml is a mixed-paradigm language. If you want to, you can use a reference (or mutable record field) to "keep" a tree as it changes value, just as in ordinary imperative programming.

**Edit:**

You might think the following session shows a modification of a variable x:

```
# let x = 2;;
val x : int = 2
# let x = 3;;
val x : int = 3
#
```

However, the way to look at this is that these are two different values that happen to both be named x. Because the names are the same, the old value of x is hidden. But if you had another way to access the old value, it would still be there. Maybe the following will show how things work:

```
# let x = 2;;
val x : int = 2
# let f () = x + 5;;
val f : unit -> int = <fun>
# f ();;
- : int = 7
# let x = 8;;
val x : int = 8
# f ();;
- : int = 7
#
```

Creating a new thing named `x` with the value 8 doesn't affect what `f` does. It's still using the same old `x` that existed when it was defined.

**Edit 2:**

Removing a value from a tree immutably is analogous to adding a value. I.e., you don't actually modify an existing tree. You create a new tree without the value that you don't want. Just as inserting doesn't copy the whole tree (it re-uses large parts of the previous tree), so deleting won't copy the whole tree either. Any parts of the tree that aren't changed can be re-used in the new tree.

**Edit 3**

Here's some code to remove a value from a tree. It uses a helper function that adjoins two trees that are known to be disjoint (furthermore all values in a are less than all values in b):

```
let rec adjoin a b =
    match a, b with
    | Leaf, _ -> b
    | _, Leaf -> a
    | Node (v, al, ar), _ -> Node (v, al, adjoin ar b)

let rec delete x = function
    | Leaf -> Leaf
    | Node (v, l, r) ->
        if x = v then adjoin l r
        else if x < v then Node (v, delete x l, r)
        else Node (v, l, delete x r)
```

(Hope I didn't just spoil your homework!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, I understand that it is one process to transform a list to a bst and the final value is the tree and bound to tree_of_list. But what if the list later on get one more value? should I run the transformation again? Basically what I am trying to ask is that should I change the value of a variable (tree_of_list in your code)?

Comment: The essence of FP is that you don't change values. This is what you need to wrap your head around! A list can't get a new value later--it's immutable. To process the tree further, you would pass it along to new functions.

Comment: ok, so it has nothing to do with changing variable's value? simply say, if I have `let x = 1;;` then I have `let x = 2;;`, it is fine, right?

Comment: These are two different `x`s, not the same `x`. The toplevel is a little misleading in this way.

Comment: two different `x`? but if I have the 2nd `let x = 2`, the first `x` won't be approachable forever, right?

Comment: (StackOverflow frowns on "chatting" in these comments, so I'll add some text to my answer.)

Comment: Also, could you please explain a bit about `immutable` when removing a node from a `BST`? I mean, when insert, it is easy to think, every time, I insert and then when I insert the 2nd time, I just use the tree from the first insert. How about I already have a tree, then removing a node from the tree, I have to modify the existing tree, right? or I have to copy the whole tree and remove the node from the newly copied tree?

Comment: `remove x tree` would return a new tree without `x` in it. If you'd like to reclaim the space used by that element you will have to let the old tree go out of scope so that the garbage collector sweeps it away.

Comment: Could you please write a simple `remove` function in your answer? I still can't image how to remove x without modifying the original tree. Am I suppose to insert every node until I meet the x, then insert every node which start from x?

Comment: Thanks very much. I understand the point now. So even in the process of deleting, I anyway for each node create a new Node.

Comment: No, this is not my home work. I am a 30 year old man self-learning OCaml. lol

Comment: I am really happy that I really understand the point here and I think keeping the data structure / value immutable bring real conveniences. thanks Jeffrey

Comment: could you please answer this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460786/the-correct-way-to-build-a-binary-search-tree-in-ocaml