# The correct way to build a Binary Search Tree in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, binary-search-tree

Ok, I have written a `binary search tree` in OCaml.

```
type 'a bstree = 
    |Node of 'a * 'a bstree * 'a bstree
    |Leaf


let rec insert x = function
    |Leaf -> Node (x, Leaf, Leaf)
    |Node (y, left, right) as node -> 
        if x < y then
            Node (y, insert x left, right)
        else if x > y then
            Node (y, left, insert x right)
        else
            node
```

---

The above code was said to be good in [The right way to use a data structure in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440719/the-right-way-to-use-a-data-structure-in-ocaml)

However, I found a problem. This `insert` will only work when building a bst from a list in one go, such as

```
let rec set_of_list = function
     [] > empty
   | x :: l > insert x (set_of_list l);;
```

So if we build a bst from a list continuously, no problem, we can get a complete bst which has all nodes from the list.

However, if I have a bst built previously and now I wish to insert a node, **then the resulting bst won't have complete nodes from the previous tree**, **am I right?**

Then how should I write a bst in OCaml so that we create a new bst with all nodes from previous tree to keep the previous tree immutable? If every time I need to copy all nodes from old bst, will that impact the performance?

---

**Edit:**

So let's say initially, a bst is created with one node `t1 = (10, Leaf, Leaf)`.

then I do `let t2 = insert 5 t1`, then I get `t2 = (10, (5, Leaf, Leaf), Leaf)`, right? inside t2, let's give a variable `c1 to the child node (5, Leaf, Leaf)`

then I do `let t5 = insert 12 t2`, then I get `t3 = (10, (5, Leaf, Leaf), (15, Leaf, Leaf))`. let's give a variable `c2 to the child node (5, Leaf, Leaf)`

So my question is whether `c1 == c2`? Are the two `(5, Leaf, Leaf)`s in t2 and t3 exactly the same?

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference between the call that inserts the second item in the list and a second invocation somewhere else in your code that inserts a new value. insert x old_tree should return the new tree as a result.

Comment: Have you tried doing it and failed, or are you guessing?

Comment: I don't understand what is the question you're asking. "then the resulting bst won't have complete nodes from the previous tree, am I right" -> I don't understand what you want to say in this sentence but you must know that the new BST will share all its nodes with the old one except the ones that are on the path to the new node (the pointers in the new BST will have the same value than in the old one) so there is no copy of nodes.

Comment: @Thomash It is my fault, I overlooked something. Please see edit for the new question

Comment: Be careful with the use of `==` vs `=` (although in this situation that won't matter).

Comment: @didierc thanks. I used `==` on purpose here as I wanna know whether the two parts are exactly the same thing.

Comment: I understand. It was a good question actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the accepted answer to the linked question.
To be specific this line here:

> let tree_of_list l = List.fold_right insert l Leaf

Work out the chain of what is happening. Take the list 1,2,3.

First we have no tree and the result of insert 1 Leaf.

call this T1

Next is the tree generated by insert 2 T1

call this T2

Then the tree generated by insert 3 T2

This is what is returned as the result of Tree_of_list.

If we call the result T3 then somewhere else in code call insert 4 T3 there is no difference in the result returned from insert than in calling Tree_of_list with the list 1,2,3,4.

Comment: This is what I was going to say. There's no difference between the initial creation of the tree and "later". In all cases you're preserving an old tree while re-using parts of it to make a new tree. There are performance implications to using immutable data like this, but the amazing thing about FP is that the costs are usually modest and the benefits are significant.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to answer the sharing part of your question. The short answer is yes, the two parts of the two trees will be identical. The reason immutable data works so well is that there are no limitations on the possible sharing. That's why FP works so well.

Here's a session that does what you describe:

```
# let t1 = Node (10, Leaf, Leaf);;
val t1 : int bstree = Node (10, Leaf, Leaf)
# let t2 = insert 5 t1;;
val t2 : int bstree = Node (10, Node (5, Leaf, Leaf), Leaf)
# let t3 = insert 12 t2;;
val t3 : int bstree = Node (10, Node (5, Leaf, Leaf), Node (12, Leaf, Leaf))
# let Node (_, c1, _) = t2;;
val c1 : int bstree = Node (5, Leaf, Leaf)
# let Node (_, c2, _) = t3;;
val c2 : int bstree = Node (5, Leaf, Leaf)
# c1 == c2;;
- : bool = true
```

The long answer is that there's no guarantee that the two parts will be identical. If the compiler and/or runtime can see a reason to copy a subtree, it's also free to do that. There are cases (as in distributed processing) where that would be a better choice. Again the great thing about FP is that there are no limitations on sharing, which means that sharing is neither required nor forbidden in such cases.

Comment: Can I understand in this way: in the insert process of my code, any sub parts that do not require changing will be shared as they are not changing and that does not violate the immutable rule of FP. But if a sub part is going to be changed in the tree (for example, the new node will be inserted into a branch of tree), then that sub part is returned as a new Node as indicated here: if x < y then
            Node (y, insert x left, right).....

Comment: excellent answer for the sharing part. but can I mark @stonemetal answer? as his answer answered the major part. but thank you Jeffrey.

Comment: I'd say this is a good way to think about it. At the same time you should realize that OCaml is straightforward: the code more or less just does what you say. There's no special work to make sharing happen. Every occurrence of an id refers to the same (identical) thing, that's really all that's going on.

Comment: tbh, I hated ocaml at the very beginning. Now I am quite a fan of OCaml, especially after learning a bit of SML. OCaml is very convenient.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, could you please review my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759932/simple-non-optimal-unionfind-in-ocaml ?