# OCaml dictionary update

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml and am trying to learn how to update dictionary and deal with if/else conditionals. 
I wrote the following code to check whether the dictionary has some key. If not, add a default value for that key. Finally print it out.

```
module MyUsers = Map.Make(String)
let myGraph = MyUsers.empty;;
let myGraph = MyUsers.add "test" "preset" myGraph in
try
  let mapped = MyUsers.find "test" myGraph
with
    Not_found -> let myGraph = MyUsers.add "test" "default" myGraph in
Printf.printf "value for the key is now %s\n" (MyUsers.find "test" myGraph)
```

The error message I have now is `syntax error for line 6: with`
What is wrong here? Also, when to use `in` `;` or`;;` ? 
I have done some google searches and understand that `in` seems to define some scope before the next `;;`. But it is still very vague to me. Could you please explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that, except at the top level, `let` must be followed by `in`. The expression looks like `let` *variable* `=` *expression1* `in` *expression2*. The idea is that the given variable is bound to the value of *expression1* in the body of *expression2*. You have a `let` with no `in`.

It's hard to answer your more general question. It's easier to work with some specific code and a specific question.

However, a semicolon `;` is used to separate two values that you want to be evaluated in sequence. The first should have type `unit` (meaning that it doesn't have a useful value).

In my opinion, the double semicolon `;;` is used only in the top-level to tell the interpreter that you're done typing and that it should evaluate what you've given it so far. Some people use `;;` in actual OCaml code, but I do not.

Your code indicates strongly that you're thinking imperatively about OCaml maps. OCaml maps are immutable; that is, you can't change the value of a map. You can only produce a new map with different contents than the old one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will `let myDict = MyUsers.add "test" "test2" myDict in` update the dictionary myDict?

Comment: No, nothing will update a dictionary, as I said :-) Dictionaries are immutable. This expression creates a new dictionary that happens to have the same name as the old one.

Comment: I see but is the original one overwritten as they have the same name?

Comment: That is a low level detail. In practice any value not reachable will be reclaimed by GC (eventually). But the value could be reachable depending on what the code looks like. Maybe see this SO page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440719/the-right-way-to-use-a-data-structure-in-ocaml/14441032#14441032