# OCaml variable counting

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to achieve the following: Finding the element at a specific index.

So if I had a list of `[5; 2; 3; 6]` and ask for the element at index `2`, it would return `3`.

```
let counter = 0;;
let increase_counter c = c + 1;;
let rec get_val x n = match x with
    [] -> -1
  | (h::t) ->
    if (counter = n) then
      h
    else
      increase_counter counter ; get_val t n
;;
```

But this code is giving me a bug saying that `-1` is not of type 'unit'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeffrey Scofield said, you should write `let counter = ref 0` to make `counter` mutable. Now, you can use the built in `incr` function to increment it (equivalent to `counter := !counter + 1`), and you'll get its value with `!counter`.

There is also a problem in your algorithm : if the counter is equal to `n`, you return the head of the list... you mean : if the head of the list is equal to `n`, you return the counter.

Your program is then :

```
let counter = ref 0;;

let rec get_val x n = match x with
    [] -> -1
  | (h::t) ->
    if (h = n) then
      !counter
    else
      begin incr counter ; get_val t n end
;;
```

Note that I've added `begin` and `end` around the else block so it can be interpreted as a sequence of instructions.

Your program now works, but it is not the best way to solve this problem with ocaml.

You should write something like

```
let get_val x n =
  let rec get_val_aux x n counter = match x with
    | [] -> -1
    | h :: _ when h = n -> counter
    | _ :: t -> get_val_aux t n (succ counter)
  in
    get_val_aux x n 0
;;
```

Here, we add a parameter to the `get_val_aux` function which we increment at each call. This function is nested within the `get_val` function to hide this additional parameter which is initialized with `0` on the first call.

Instead of using an `if` statement, we use the `when` condition to know when the element has been found, and add a new case to match the last case (not found). Note the use of the `_` wildcard to avoid an unused variable.

The `succ` function (for successor) only adds `1` to its parameter. It is equivalent to `counter + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with this code. If you ignore your immediate problem for a moment, you are treating OCaml variables like the variables of an imperative language. However, OCaml variables are immutable. This function

```
let increase_counter c = c + 1
```

Doesn't change the value of any variable. It just returns a number 1 bigger than what you give it.

The only error I get from the toplevel when I enter your code is for this expression:

```
  increase_counter counter ; get_val t n
```

The compiler is warning you that the expression before `;` is supposed to be executed for its side effects. I.e., it should almost always have type `unit`. Since (as I say) your function `increase_counter` returns an int, the compiler is warning you about this.

Comment: OCaml variables are immutable, you can't change their values! :-) I would look for another way to do this (an extra parameter of your function, perhaps). However if you insist on programming imperatively you need to use a reference (`let counter = ref 0`).

Comment: lol alright fine thanks. I'm so used to imperative languages I can't think of any other way.

Comment: wait but if I do let x = 1 and then do let x = 5 and do print_int x it prints 5 not 1, so am I not changing the variable?

Comment: It is *not* changing the variable. You have two different variables with the same name. The old variable still exists. See this SO page for a longer description of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440719/the-right-way-to-use-a-data-structure-in-ocaml/14441032#14441032